# Why does the Google Slide ruler shift?

Tags: google-slides

I'm confused why my Google Slides show a ruler that looks like this when no text is selected:

[image]

But then shifts once I select the text box, creating two "1"s. Is there a way to make the ruler immutable, or am I missing a functionality?
[image]